# How to pass single element of array to procedure?

Tags: delphi

Example

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var x:integer;
begin
   SetLength(MyArray,10)
   for x:=0 to 9 do FillWithRandomNumbers(MyArray[x]);
end;

Procedure FillWithRandomNumbers(var MyArray: Array of double);
begin
  MyArray:=Random; //<-I have no idea what to do here :(
end;
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass single element to procedure in order to perform some task on specified array cell. For example procedure FillWithRandomNumbers should take MyArray[2] and fill this cell with random number.

Answer (score 4):

You want to pass a single array element, yet your procedure expects a full array. To directly answer your actual question, your procedure should be defined as:

```
Procedure FillWithRandomNumber(var Value: double);  
begin
  Value:= Random;
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var x:integer;
begin
   SetLength(MyArray,10)
   for x:=0 to 9 do FillWithRandomNumber(MyArray[x]);
end;
```

Or you could do it like this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   SetLength(MyArray, 10);
   FillWithRandomNumbers(MyArray);
end;

Procedure FillWithRandomNumbers(var SomeArray: Array of double);
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  for X := Low(SomeArray) to High(SomeArray) do begin
    SomeArray[X] := Random;
  end;
end;
```

Or to be even more simple, just don't use a procedure at all:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  X: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(MyArray, 10);
  for X := 0 to High(Array) do begin
    MyArray[X]:= Random;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes I know It can be done simpler. It was just an extreme simple example. 
Thank you for first solution.

Comment: Another possibility is to use the result of a funciton:

function GetRandomNumber;
begin
  Result:=Random; 
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var x:integer;
begin
   SetLength(MyArray,10)
   for x:=0 to 9 do MyArray[x] := GetRandomNumber();
end;